# CSV parsing: split row data depending on criteria

Tags: python, list, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse a csv file into a particular format in python.

The file looks like this:

```
    iteration_number,iteration_name,Gb_sec,Gb_sec,trans_sec,trans_sec,usec,usec
    1,tcp_stream-64B-1i,  0.5908,  0.5908,,,,,
    2,tcp_stream-64B-8i,  4.6030,  4.6030,,,,,
    4,tcp_stream-16384B-1i,  9.6810,  9.6810,,,,,
    5,tcp_stream-16384B-8i, 20.0800, 20.0800,,,,,
    7,tcp_rr-64B-1i,,,  22040.0000,  22040.0000,  45.4600,  45.4600,
    8,tcp_rr-64B-8i,,, 144000.0000, 144000.0000,  55.5600,  55.5600,
    10,tcp_rr-16384B-1i,,,  12440.0000,  12440.0000,  80.4900,  80.4900,
    11,tcp_rr-16384B-8i,,,  75580.0000,  75580.0000, 105.9000, 105.9000,
```

In this case I have 2 columns each of Gb_sec, trans_sec and usec, but it could be N number of columns meaning I could have 1-N columns of each of the header. But it always would be equal for the metric mentioned.

What I'm trying to achieve is to parse this file into a python list. Which looks like the following, This is the format I want the data to be in:

```
[
[""],
[system_name],
[tcp_stream-64B],
[instance count, Gb_sec, Gb_sec],
[1i, 0.5908,  0.5908]
[8i, 4.6030,  4.6030]
[""],
[system_name],
[tcp_stream-16384B],
[instance count, Gb_sec, Gb_sec],
[1i, 9.6810,  9.6810],
[8i, 20.0800, 20.0800],
[""],
[system_name],
[tcp_rr-64B],
[instance count, trans_sec, trans_sec]
[1i, 22040.0000,  22040.0000]
[8i, 144000.0000, 144000.0000],
[""],
[system_name],
[tcp_rr-64B],
[instance count, usec, usec],
[1i,45.4600,  45.4600],
[1i, 55.5600,  55.5600],
.......
```

So, far I am able to parse the file and get the required format but I'm not able to separate the trans_sec and usec in the same row into different list while maintaining the python list format required. If the number of columns are constant then I could just slice the rows and feed to different list by saying row[:2] and row[3:] but I'm confused as to how to maintain the format while doing so. Any tips would be very helpful.

This is what I have so far, which works without the trans_sec and usec seperation:

```
    results = []
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        iteration_name = []
        for index, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
            instance_result = [row['iteration_name'].split('-')[2]]
            header_row = ['instance count']
            
            # pop failed runs
            if 'fail' in row['iteration_name']:
                continue

            # remove empty values
            row = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if v is not '' and k is not None}

            if iteration_name != row['iteration_name'].split('-')[:2]:
                header_row += [i.split(':')[0] for i in list(row.keys())[2:]]
                iteration_name = row['iteration_name'].split('-')[:2]

                results.append([""])
                results.append([system_name])
                results.append(["-".join(iteration_name)])
                results.append(header_row)

            instance_result += list(row.values())[2:]
            results.append(instance_result)

    return results
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to do this task using `pandas` - `pd.read_csv` method will read from a `csv` file and give you a proper `dataframe`

Comment: Seems excess to use pandas when I could get the data via csv module or even simple file module.The problem is to be able to parse the data into a format that is required. Do you think pandas would help in that regard or add more complexity? This seems like a simple problem but I couldn't get my head around to look at the data in a different perspective for it to work in a neat way.